# How to format a date depending on the locale used?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a date that I would like to format depending on what country the user is from.

The date: 10th of March 2015.

Let's say the user is from USA, I'd like: 03/10/15

Let's say the user is from France, I'd like 10/03/15

I guess I could check if the locale is like `en-US` and `fr-FR` and format it accordingly but is there a way to make it automatic and for all locales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `defaultTimeZone` of `NSDateFormatter()`

```
var dateFmt = NSDateFormatter()
dateFmt.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the NSDateFormatter styles:

```
NSDateFormatterNoStyle
NSDateFormatterShortStyle 
NSDateFormatterMediumStyle
NSDateFormatterLongStyle
NSDateFormatterFullStyle
```

Or if you already have a format string in mind (like "MM-DD-YYYY") you can pass it through `[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:];`